# Use beautifulsoup parse a pom.xml, it works well on windows, but fails on centos

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I use beautifulsoup to parse a pom.xml and remove some tags from it. The script worked well on Windows7, but it failed when I ran it with the same pom.xml on CentOS. Any ideas?

Here is part of the script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


pom_file = open(filename, "r", encoding="UTF-8")
pom = BeautifulSoup(pom_file, "xml")
print(pom)
```

When run above script, it will print the content of my pom.xml correctly on Windows7, but it will print `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` on CentOS.

Comment: What's the _BeautifulSoup_ version on each _OS_? Also on _Lnx_ it seems to stop after the 1st line, so make sure you don't have an _eoln_ mismatch.

Comment: @CristiFati Both versions of the _BeautifulSoup_ are 4.6.0. How to check if I mismatch some _eoln_

Comment: Use a text editor that supports displaying "non printable chars" (any decent editor/viewer has it: _Notepad++_, _Sublime_, _mc_'s editor, ....). But this is just a guess. Is the file identical in the 2 cases? What about _python_ version (and _xml_ parser version)?

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks for your advice! I solve this problem finally, it is exactly the fault of _eoln_ . I use **dos2unix** convert the pom.xml to UNIX format and my script works now.

Comment: Very good! I know how frustrating can be getting stuck because of such things.